# Filtering pattern noise in scanned prints with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to remove some pattern noise from some prints I have scanned. I am using Python and OpenCV.

So far I have this:

```
medianBlur(img, 5)
fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(img, None, 3, 3, 5, 11)
```

These filters give decent results when combined, but both still either make the image too soft or leave some noise patterns in the image.

I am just asking if there is some other filter for this kind of pattern noise that I have missed or what I have found is the best that can be done.

These are two samples of what I'm trying to filter:
https://mega.nz/file/9gsGERwR#uHDlr9KAseTf5lC0lMQwNfzcyZ3l_xENWa0hskY6dIY
https://mega.nz/file/hx1ADTaK#f6azLh4uasIGuu2m8EPxCfto72XpukQLQQhStssQiXw

P.S.: Yes, the prints are copyrighted, from a boardgame I have bought, but I do not intend to distribute the scanned images, they are just for a personal project that I am making, to play the game with my friend online, due to the pandemic we cannot meet in person.

Comment: The noise is periodic, better to make the filtering in the frequency domain.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have studied fft filtering since yesterday and I have great results. Many thanks.